# Two scrollbar using the same css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I'm using [custom scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/), add one scrollbar is very easy, but if I want to add second they twice use one mCustomScrollbar.css I don't know how to change that second div. I was looking on code on [demo custom scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html) but this just fail.

**JQUERY**

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".suwak").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<link href="scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<div class="suwak"> content with first scrollbar </div>
<div class="suwak2"> content with second scrollbar </div>
```

**Some simply CSS**

```
.suwak{
position:relative;
width:475px;
height:300px;
background-color: #000e1b;
color: white;
overflow:hidden
margin-top:160px;
margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another class on div with class="suwak", this will run your scrollbar and your second class will help override your first class. In css you are saying, if something has both classes, use new style. In css your selector would be .suwak.suwak2, no space between classes in css.

```
<div class="suwak"> content with first scrollbar </div>
<div class="suwak suwak2"> content with second scrollbar </div>

.suwak{
position:relative;
width:475px;
height:300px;
background-color: #000e1b;
color: white;
overflow:hidden
margin-top:160px;
margin-left: 15px;
}

.suwak.suwak2 {
/*new stile*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use second class as well? is it something that you don't know how many DIVs will be there to have same scrollbar?

If it is limited to 2 only, then try

```
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".suwak").mCustomScrollbar();
    $(".suwak2").mCustomScrollbar();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Or you can mention same class for second DIV as well. I have suggested this as per my observation of the code you posted.

Comment: but this dont solve my problem I can load two scrollbar in diffrent divs, but I can't changeing these css. I need to take some properties from mCustomScrollBar.css and extend this with changeing them in the same time?

Comment: It means you dont want the second div to use the same CSS?

Comment: mmm meaby I don't know.. how second scrolbbar will know that he must use second css?

Comment: you will need to mention all classes with second class name in start of every style rule. As this is driven by plugin, I do not see any other approach.

Comment: I was trying do this but it fail, short example please

Comment: You will have to maintain it as `.suwak2 .yourscrollbarStylerule` and so on.